# Handling spacing between multiple lines of a title text

Tags: spacing, line-spacing

For my thesis I have a very long title and it spans three lines. The spacing between the lines are coming out to be very less. I tried adding `\smallskip'. This has improved the spacing between first and second line, but not between second and third. How can this be achieved?

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\rule{\textwidth}{1.6pt}\vspace*{-\baselineskip}\vspace*{2pt} % Thick horizontal line
\rule{\textwidth}{0.4pt}\\[\baselineskip] % Thin horizontal line

{\LARGE\textcolor{navy} {\smallskip \uppercase {Towards automating the generation of derivative nouns in Sanskrit by simulating Pāṇini}}
} % Title

\rule{\textwidth}{0.4pt}\vspace*{-\baselineskip}\vspace{3.2pt} % Thin horizontal line
\rule{\textwidth}{1.6pt}\\[\baselineskip] % Thick horizontal line
```

Comment: Please, Could you give a MWE ?

Comment: \smallskip cause one skip.  What you want is \baselieskip=1.5\baselineskip

Answer (score 4):

I would provide the following instructions:

- Most importantly, add a `\par` instruction at the end of the material to be set in `\LARGE`, to get better line spacing.
- Remove the instruction `\smallskip` at the start of the LARGE material
- Add three `\noindent` instructions.
- Add a `\medskip` instruction to even out the distances between the title material and the pairs of rules.
- Fix the spelling of the color for the title material; I believe it should be "Navy", not "navy".

[image]

(I don't know which font you use; Computer/Latin Modern -- the font used in the screenshot -- doesn't appear to be set up to recognize the uppercase forms of the characters `ā` and `ṇ`.)

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage[textwidth=370pt]{geometry} % choose textwidth here
\begin{document}

\noindent
\rule{\textwidth}{1.6pt}\vspace*{-\baselineskip}\vspace*{2pt} % Thick horizontal line
\rule{\textwidth}{0.4pt}\\ % Thin horizontal line

\noindent
{\LARGE\textcolor{Navy}{\uppercase {Towards automating 
 the generation of derivative nouns in Sanskrit by simulating Pāṇini}}
\par} % Title

\medskip
\noindent
\rule{\textwidth}{0.4pt}\vspace*{-\baselineskip}\vspace{3.2pt} % Thin horizontal line
\rule{\textwidth}{1.6pt}\\% Thick horizontal line

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to issue `\par` before closing the scope where `\LARGE` is in effect.

You also should use `\MakeUppercase` rather than `\uppercase` and define equivalents for the UTF-8 characters `ă` and `ṇ`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage[textwidth=370pt]{geometry} % choose textwidth here
\usepackage{newunicodechar}

\newunicodechar{ā}{\=a}
\newunicodechar{ṇ}{\d{n}}

\begin{document}

\noindent
\rule{\textwidth}{1.6pt}\vspace*{-\baselineskip}\vspace*{2pt} % Thick horizontal line
\rule{\textwidth}{0.4pt}\\ % Thin horizontal line

{\noindent\LARGE\color{Navy}\MakeUppercase{Towards automating
 the generation of derivative nouns in Sanskrit by simulating Pāṇini}\par} % Title

\medskip
\noindent
\rule{\textwidth}{0.4pt}\vspace*{-\baselineskip}\vspace{3.2pt} % Thin horizontal line
\rule{\textwidth}{1.6pt}\\% Thick horizontal line

\end{document}
```

It's easier using `\color{Navy}` rather than `\textcolor{Navy}{...}`; the only required precaution is to have the `\color` instruction after `\noindent`.

[image]

You can better control the rules and the spacing before, between and after them by using the lower level `\hrule` instruction, rather than `\rule`.

Also, using `\centering` seems better.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage[textwidth=370pt]{geometry} % choose textwidth here
\usepackage{newunicodechar}

\newunicodechar{ā}{\=a}
\newunicodechar{ṇ}{\d{n}}

\begin{document}

\hrule height 1.6pt
\vspace{2pt}
\hrule height 0.4pt
\vspace{\medskipamount}

{\centering\noindent\LARGE\color{Navy}\strut\MakeUppercase{Towards automating
 the generation of derivative nouns in Sanskrit by simulating Pāṇini}\strut\par} % Title

\vspace{\medskipamount}
\hrule height 0.4pt
\vspace{2pt}
\hrule height 1.6pt

\end{document}
```

[image]